# “ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW”

Tags: perl

I am trying to install a missing Perl module ([Palm::PDB](http://p3rl.org/Palm%3a%3aPDB)) in Windows 7.

I have tried the following:

1. Using Perl Package Manager: unfortunately it does not seem to find the module I want.
2. Starting a CPAN shell in Windows using the command prompt: unfortunately it shows the following error. I have installed MinGW and also have set the path.

   ```
   D:\Scripts>perl -MCPAN -e 'shell' install Palm::PDB

   It looks like you don't have a C compiler and make utility installed.  Trying
   to install dmake and the MinGW gcc compiler using the Perl Package Manager.
   This may take a few minutes...

   ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW

   It looks like the installation of dmake and MinGW has failed.  You will not be
   able to run Makefile commands or compile C extension code.  Please check your
   internet connection and your proxy settings!
   ```

Is there any other easy way to install Perl modules on Windows?

Comment: How did you install Perl? Is it from ActiveState? Which version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is wrong with your ActiveState Perl install because it will automatically install dmake and MinGW for you.

If you have dmake.exe installed try to install MinGW by running these commands:

```
ppm install MinGW
perl Makefile.PL
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

Also MinGW and dmake are being installed into C:\Perl\site\bin. Make sure this directory is on your PATH (done by default by the ActivePerl installer).

Comment: Where do you install your Perl? Try to place it in C:\Perl.

Comment: Or try to download dmake: http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/GSAR/dmake-4.1pl1-win32.zip

Comment: I downloaded it but there is no exe inside the archive. When i tried winzip it said that the archive was dameged. Is there any other download link

Comment: Okay i found another link. Now i placed the dmake.exe into c/Perl

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to use Perl on Windows is to use a recent release of [StrawberryPerl](http://strawberryperl.com/). It has `dmake` and a C compiler (gcc) bundled. The `cpan` command just works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveState do a review of all modules they release for PPM. So it often doesn't have modules which are not in high demand, or ones which have been recently released.

The fastest way to get this working on Windows is to install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) because, out of the box, it comes with a C compiler that is ready to be used with CPAN. That will save you from all the troubles of configuring MingW.

Answer (score 1):

cpan try to find a C compiler - probably this module or some dependencies has native code (for database drivers is more common). MingW is a gcc port for Windows.

If it does not work, try to install a virtual machine with linux and install gcc :)

Comment: Or http://www.cygwin.com/. Probably the easiest way to use Perl in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I cleaned AppData folder of ActivePerl.

> C:\Users\%YOUR_USERNAME%\AppData\Local\ActiveState\ActivePerl\

Delete all data from that folder. And rerun `ppm` again! It worked.

Comment: This did not work with ActiveState Platform and Perl 5.28.1.  Seems like `MinGW`  has not been ported to ActiveState Platform?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked after clearing the content from this location C:\Users\%YOUR_USERNAME%\AppData\Local\ActiveState\ActivePerl\

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ppm install MinGW
```

Downloading ActiveState Package Repository dbimage...done
Downloading MinGW-4.6.3...done
Downloading dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Unpacking MinGW-4.6.3...done
Unpacking dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Generating HTML for MinGW-4.6.3...done
Generating HTML for dmake-4.11.20080107...done
Updating files in site area...done
3697 files installed

Thank you @Void

Comment: This did not work with ActiveState Platform and Perl 5.28.1.  Seems like `MinGW`  has not been ported to ActiveState Platform?

Answer (score 0):

perl -MCPAN -e shell

> install SOAP::Lite

if anyone has same issue on windows 10, use the above command on windows command line. It worked for me.