# Why will it not install DBI?

Tags: perl, xampp, cpan

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10.
Running Apache and mySQL, works fine. I was testing Perl, and it worked too. However it can't connect to mySQL, so I tried to install DBI, but neither PPM or CPAN was recognized by DOS. So I installed ActiveState-Perl, and then used CPAN to install DBI, and you can see the result below.

Any ideas will help! Thanks!!

````
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 24 Dec 2019 06:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'DBI'
Checksum for C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TI\TIMB\DBI-1.642.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\Perl64/cpan/build for sizes
........................................................................----DONE
DEL(1/1): C:\Perl64\cpan\build\DBI-1.642-0.yml
DBI-1.642/
DBI-1.642/DBI.pm
DBI-1.642/dbipport.h
DBI-1.642/INSTALL
DBI-1.642/dbixs_rev.pl
DBI-1.642/Perl.xs
DBI-1.642/dbivport.h
DBI-1.642/LICENSE
DBI-1.642/dbi_sql.h
DBI-1.642/Changes
DBI-1.642/dbilogstrip.PL
DBI-1.642/MANIFEST
DBI-1.642/ex/
DBI-1.642/dbiprof.PL
DBI-1.642/Driver.xst
DBI-1.642/t/
DBI-1.642/DBI.xs
DBI-1.642/test.pl
DBI-1.642/README.md
DBI-1.642/dbd_xsh.h
DBI-1.642/typemap
DBI-1.642/dbixs_rev.h
DBI-1.642/dbiproxy.PL
DBI-1.642/DBIXS.h
DBI-1.642/META.yml
DBI-1.642/lib/
DBI-1.642/Makefile.PL
DBI-1.642/Driver_xst.h
DBI-1.642/META.json
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/
DBI-1.642/lib/Bundle/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/
DBI-1.642/lib/Win32/
DBI-1.642/lib/Win32/DBIODBC.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/DBM.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/NullP.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/File/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Proxy.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/ExampleP.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/File.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Mem.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Sponge.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/classic.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/pedantic.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/Base.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Policy/rush.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/null.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/corostream.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/File/Developers.pod
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/File/Roadmap.pod
DBI-1.642/lib/DBD/File/HowTo.pod
DBI-1.642/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Util/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/PurePerl.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Profile.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProfileData.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/W32ODBC.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProxyServer.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProfileSubs.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/SQL/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/SQL/Nano.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/ProfileDumper/Apache.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/Metadata.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/Developers.pod
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine/HowTo.pod
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoType.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfoReturn.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ODBC.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Const/GetInfo/ANSI.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Execute.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Response.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Request.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/pipeone.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/stream.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Transport/Base.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/DataDumper.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Storable.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Gofer/Serializer/Base.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Util/_accessor.pm
DBI-1.642/lib/DBI/Util/CacheMemory.pm
DBI-1.642/t/pod.t
DBI-1.642/t/90sql_type_cast.t
DBI-1.642/t/80proxy.t
DBI-1.642/t/51dbm_file.t
DBI-1.642/t/16destroy.t
DBI-1.642/t/lib.pl
DBI-1.642/t/73cachedkids.t
DBI-1.642/t/40profile.t
DBI-1.642/t/02dbidrv.t
DBI-1.642/t/86gofer_fail.t
DBI-1.642/t/53sqlengine_adv.t
DBI-1.642/t/06attrs.t
DBI-1.642/t/65transact.t
DBI-1.642/t/01basics.t
DBI-1.642/t/48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
DBI-1.642/t/03handle.t
DBI-1.642/t/05concathash.t
DBI-1.642/t/41prof_dump.t
DBI-1.642/t/14utf8.t
DBI-1.642/t/07kids.t
DBI-1.642/t/11fetch.t
DBI-1.642/t/19fhtrace.t
DBI-1.642/t/91_store_warning.t
DBI-1.642/t/87gofer_cache.t
DBI-1.642/t/54_dbd_mem.t
DBI-1.642/t/72childhandles.t
DBI-1.642/t/49dbd_file.t
DBI-1.642/t/85gofer.t
DBI-1.642/t/12quote.t
DBI-1.642/t/04mods.t
DBI-1.642/t/10examp.t
DBI-1.642/t/52dbm_complex.t
DBI-1.642/t/35thrclone.t
DBI-1.642/t/50dbm_simple.t
DBI-1.642/t/15array.t
DBI-1.642/t/31methcache.t
DBI-1.642/t/09trace.t
DBI-1.642/t/60preparse.t
DBI-1.642/t/20meta.t
DBI-1.642/t/pod-coverage.t
DBI-1.642/t/70callbacks.t
DBI-1.642/t/42prof_data.t
DBI-1.642/t/13taint.t
DBI-1.642/t/43prof_env.t
DBI-1.642/t/30subclass.t
DBI-1.642/t/08keeperr.t
DBI-1.642/ex/profile.pl
DBI-1.642/ex/corogofer.pl
DBI-1.642/ex/perl_dbi_nulls_test.pl
Configuring T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.642.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Your perl was compiled with gcc (version 4.6.3), okay.
Use of uninitialized value $DBI::DBD::Config{"cc"} in string eq at lib/DBI/DBD.pm line 3315.
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer:
t/zvg_01basics.t
t/zvg_02dbidrv.t
t/zvg_03handle.t
t/zvg_04mods.t
t/zvg_05concathash.t
t/zvg_06attrs.t
t/zvg_07kids.t
t/zvg_08keeperr.t
t/zvg_09trace.t
t/zvg_10examp.t
t/zvg_11fetch.t
t/zvg_12quote.t
t/zvg_13taint.t
t/zvg_14utf8.t
t/zvg_15array.t
t/zvg_16destroy.t
t/zvg_19fhtrace.t
t/zvg_20meta.t
t/zvg_30subclass.t
t/zvg_31methcache.t
t/zvg_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvg_40profile.t
t/zvg_41prof_dump.t
t/zvg_42prof_data.t
t/zvg_43prof_env.t
t/zvg_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvg_49dbd_file.t
t/zvg_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvg_51dbm_file.t
t/zvg_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvg_53sqlengine_adv.t
t/zvg_54_dbd_mem.t
t/zvg_60preparse.t
t/zvg_65transact.t
t/zvg_70callbacks.t
t/zvg_72childhandles.t
t/zvg_73cachedkids.t
t/zvg_80proxy.t
t/zvg_85gofer.t
t/zvg_86gofer_fail.t
t/zvg_87gofer_cache.t
t/zvg_90sql_type_cast.t
t/zvg_91_store_warning.t
Creating test wrappers for DBI::SQL::Nano:
t/zvn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvn_49dbd_file.t
t/zvn_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvn_51dbm_file.t
t/zvn_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvn_85gofer.t
Creating test wrappers for DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvp_01basics.t
t/zvp_02dbidrv.t
t/zvp_03handle.t
t/zvp_04mods.t
t/zvp_05concathash.t
t/zvp_06attrs.t
t/zvp_07kids.t
t/zvp_08keeperr.t
t/zvp_09trace.t
t/zvp_10examp.t
t/zvp_11fetch.t
t/zvp_12quote.t
t/zvp_13taint.t
t/zvp_14utf8.t
t/zvp_15array.t
t/zvp_16destroy.t
t/zvp_19fhtrace.t
t/zvp_20meta.t
t/zvp_30subclass.t
t/zvp_31methcache.t
t/zvp_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvp_40profile.t
t/zvp_41prof_dump.t
t/zvp_42prof_data.t
t/zvp_43prof_env.t
t/zvp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvp_49dbd_file.t
t/zvp_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvp_51dbm_file.t
t/zvp_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvp_53sqlengine_adv.t
t/zvp_54_dbd_mem.t
t/zvp_60preparse.t
t/zvp_65transact.t
t/zvp_70callbacks.t
t/zvp_72childhandles.t
t/zvp_73cachedkids.t
t/zvp_80proxy.t
t/zvp_85gofer.t
t/zvp_86gofer_fail.t
t/zvp_87gofer_cache.t
t/zvp_90sql_type_cast.t
t/zvp_91_store_warning.t
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::SQL::Nano:
t/zvxgn_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvxgn_49dbd_file.t
t/zvxgn_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvxgn_51dbm_file.t
t/zvxgn_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvxgn_85gofer.t
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxgp_01basics.t
t/zvxgp_02dbidrv.t
t/zvxgp_03handle.t
t/zvxgp_04mods.t
t/zvxgp_05concathash.t
t/zvxgp_06attrs.t
t/zvxgp_07kids.t
t/zvxgp_08keeperr.t
t/zvxgp_09trace.t
t/zvxgp_10examp.t
t/zvxgp_11fetch.t
t/zvxgp_12quote.t
t/zvxgp_13taint.t
t/zvxgp_14utf8.t
t/zvxgp_15array.t
t/zvxgp_16destroy.t
t/zvxgp_19fhtrace.t
t/zvxgp_20meta.t
t/zvxgp_30subclass.t
t/zvxgp_31methcache.t
t/zvxgp_35thrclone.t (use threads)
t/zvxgp_40profile.t
t/zvxgp_41prof_dump.t
t/zvxgp_42prof_data.t
t/zvxgp_43prof_env.t
t/zvxgp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvxgp_49dbd_file.t
t/zvxgp_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvxgp_51dbm_file.t
t/zvxgp_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvxgp_53sqlengine_adv.t
t/zvxgp_54_dbd_mem.t
t/zvxgp_60preparse.t
t/zvxgp_65transact.t
t/zvxgp_70callbacks.t
t/zvxgp_72childhandles.t
t/zvxgp_73cachedkids.t
t/zvxgp_80proxy.t
t/zvxgp_85gofer.t
t/zvxgp_86gofer_fail.t
t/zvxgp_87gofer_cache.t
t/zvxgp_90sql_type_cast.t
t/zvxgp_91_store_warning.t
Creating test wrappers for DBI::SQL::Nano + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvxnp_49dbd_file.t
t/zvxnp_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvxnp_51dbm_file.t
t/zvxnp_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvxnp_85gofer.t
Creating test wrappers for DBD::Gofer + DBI::SQL::Nano + DBI::PurePerl:
t/zvxgnp_48dbi_dbd_sqlengine.t
t/zvxgnp_49dbd_file.t
t/zvxgnp_50dbm_simple.t
t/zvxgnp_51dbm_file.t
t/zvxgnp_52dbm_complex.t
t/zvxgnp_85gofer.t
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Use of uninitialized value $m[8] in join or string at C:/Perl64/site/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 343.

    I see you're using perl 5.028001 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread, okay.
    Remember to actually *read* the README file!
    Use  'make' to build the software (dmake or nmake on Windows).
    Then 'make test' to execute self tests.
    Then 'make install' to install the DBI and then delete this working
    directory before unpacking and building any DBD::* drivers.

    Windows users need to use the correct make command.
    That may be nmake or dmake depending on which Perl you are using.
    If using the Win32 ActiveState build then it is recommended that you
    use the ppm utility to fetch and install a prebuilt DBI instead.

Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBI
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  TIMB/DBI-1.642.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for T/TI/TIMB/DBI-1.642.tar.gz
'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
  TIMB/DBI-1.642.tar.gz
  dmake -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 TIMB/DBI-1.642.tar.gz                        : make NO

cpan>```
````

Comment: *"'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command.."* : Looks like the `dmake` executable is not supported any more. [Here](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/dmake-4.12.2.2) I found an executable from 2014, can you try it? If it is too old, you might need to use `gmake` instead. See also [How to install dmake with perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56972534/2173773), [dmake not found when installing Perl module using CPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58104250/2173773)

Comment: But how do I chance that? I thought the installer would figure that out by itself? :) Should I go for gmake or the one in the link?

All this installation stuff is driving me crazy. two month ago I was struggling with the same issue on my mac, but ended giving up. Now the same issue on my PC... sigh! .... -  I only want to be coding stuff, not all this installation stuff. :-(

Comment: IIRC, `cpan dmake` will install it. (Didn't it used to do that automatically???)

Comment: @daxim, They're not using XAMPP. They were, but switched to ActivePerl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, ActiveState Perl would automatically install `dmake` and `MinGW` for you, see [“ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10545976/2173773).

I tried to install `perl` version 5.28.1 using the new ActiveState Platform, see [notice](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/) at the PPM index:

> Notice! PPM is being replaced with the ActiveState Platform, which
>   enhances PPM’s build and deploy capabilities. Create your free
>   Platform account to download ActivePerl or customize Perl with the
>   packages you require and get automatic updates.

but there is no `MinGW` package when I choose "Add packages" from the "Configuration" tab at my Perl project from the [ActiveState Platform](https://platform.activestate.com/).

However, for the old PPM with `perl` version 5.24 there is a [`MinGW` package](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/MinGW/).

Also, if I try run from the Command Prompt:

```
>ppm install MinGW
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides MinGW
```

I would recommend using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) until this problem with ActivePerl is fixed.

Comment: I uninstalled ActiveState Perl, and installed Strawberry Perl instead.
Then cpan, DBI and DBD-mysql.
And changed #!"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe".