# 'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: perl, dmake

I installed ActiveState Perl and Komodo on my Windows 10 machine.  It's been working fine for the most part.  However, I can't install Perl modules in cpan like JSON::Parse or Switch because I keep getting an error:  `'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.  I've scoured the internet and can't find a way to get dmake to work so I can get past these errors and properly install the needed modules.

When I try to use cpan shell to install dmake, I get:  `Package contains both files[ChangeLog COPYING dmake.exe META.yml NEWS PATCH.TXT README.TXT] and directories[man readme startup]; not recognized as a perl package, giving up`

Thoughts?

Comment: I seems like MinGW and `dmake` are currently not available on the new ActiveState Platform, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59482376/2173773) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @HåkonHægland.  I agree - that is the kind of information I'm seeing out there.  Seems odd that ActiveState would not provide a way to install modules when using their platform.  I opened a support case with them.  If they respond, I'll post their comments here.  Worst case, I can switch to [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) as recommended in the answer you referenced above.

Comment: @patrickmdnet - That might answer the question - thanks!  I actually moved on by switching to Strawberry Perl.  If I get some time, I might re-test to see if that works.  But I appreciate you referencing that post here as it might help others.  Cheers!